# 2 GM Norms in 24 hours - first time ever?

Tags: fide, grandmaster, records, norm

Chess.com reports that 17-year-old [Frederik Svane has scored 2 GM Norms In 24 Hours](https://www.chess.com/news/view/frederik-svane-2-gm-norms-in-24-hours) and asks if this is a record:

> 17-year-old Svane, the youngest of the two brothers (Rasmus recently turned 25), scored his first GM norm in October 2021 at a round-robin in Kiel, Germany, where he finished in second place and reached the necessary 6.5 points by winning the last two rounds on demand.
>
> The second GM norm came last Friday, when Svane finished another closed GM tournament, this time at the local Hamburg Chess Club. The scenario was almost the same: he again came second with the necessary 6.5 points, this time winning the last three rounds on demand.
>
> Meanwhile, Frederik had played a pretty good Bundesliga season for his Hamburg club, where he had collected six points in the first eight rounds. You may guess it: also here, against pretty strong opposition, he needed 6.5 points for a GM norm. His opponent on Saturday, GM Eduardas Rozentalis, who had celebrated his 59th birthday the day before, didn't mind a quick draw, and so Svane had achieved something unique: two norms in a day! [Ed: Friday and Saturday are not the same day. Stick to 24 hours]

Comment: FIDE is currently looking into their data to find out whether this is a record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this was painful. The data inserted by FIDE was inconsistent, there were duplicate entries and some records didn't even exist. Anyways:

#### No, this does not seem to be a new record!

**[Peng, Li Min](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/14112620)** ([title application](https://ratings.fide.com/crt/main227056.pdf)) won two GM norms **in the same day** (*Elitzur GM Winter 2020 A Stage 1* and *Elitzur GM Winter 2020 C Stage 1* both ended on 2021-03-11)

---

I needed to check 2 large [categories of players](https://ratings.fide.com/titles_page.phtml):

1. Those who had earnt at least two GM norms (Norms tab).
2. Those who already had the GM title (Applications tab).

---

1. The JSON data is available in [this URL](https://ratings.fide.com/a_titles.php?country=latest&title=%22GM%22). We're only interested in the player's name and their id. Now, for each of the players, make a request to `https://ratings.fide.com/a_titles.php?record2=<playerId>` to get information about the norms they've earnt.
2. For those who already are GMs this is slightly harder. For each FIDE Council/PB, fetch all application by making a GET request to `https://ratings.fide.com/a_titles.php?pb=<id>` (`1 < id < 70` at the time of writing), get *only* the Grandmaster applications, for each applicant make a request to `https://ratings.fide.com/a_titles.php?record=<playerId>`. Parse the HTML and sort as above.

Combine both steps, sort and output.

[This is the JavaScript code I ran](https://gist.github.com/double-beep/848bdcc15ad1d1d348c0231422d1c2ff) to get the above results. You can copy-paste it in the console on a https://ratings.fide.com page to test for yourself.

Comment: Running the code will show more results. They're not in this answer because the data provided by FIDE was either incomplete/incorrect or I couldn't make sense out of it.